# Jupyter environment for pyspark2 and pyspark3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

In Jupyterhub_config.py, we have set c.YarnSpawner.localize_files to a single source path.

```
c.YarnSpawner.args = ['--NotebookApp.contents_manager_class="hdfscm.HDFSContentsManager"']
c.YarnSpawner.YarnClusterConfig.localize_files  = {
        'environment': {
            'source': 'hdfs:///apps/jupyterhub/jupyter.tar.gz',
            'visibility': 'public'
        }
    }
c.YarnSpawner.prologue = 'source environment/bin/activate'
```

We have configured Jupyter with pyspark2. Is there a way to configure multiple environments for each kernel?